# How do I aggregate negative values with AT END OF and SUM?

Tags: sum, aggregate, abap

I´m working on a ABAP program, in which I have to do a validation for a specific field, like the code below:

```
  SORT t_prcd BY knumh kschl.
  LOOP AT t_prcd INTO wa_prcd WHERE knumh = wa_wcocoh-knumh AND kschl = wa_wcocoh-kschl.

    IF wa_prcd-vbtyp = 'C'.

      wa_prcd-netwr = wa_prcd-netwr * ( -1 ).

      wa_prcd-kwmeng = wa_prcd-kwmeng * ( -1 ).

    ENDIF.

    AT END OF knumh.
      SUM. 
      " SUBTRACT wa_prcd-netwr FROM wa_prcd-netwr.
      MOVE EXACT wa_prcd-netwr TO wa_talv-val_vendido.
      MOVE wa_prcd-kwmeng TO wa_talv-quant_vendido.
    ENDAT.
  ENDLOOP.
```

What I need to do is: if `wa_prcd-vbtyp` is `C` the value of `wa_prcd-netwr` must be negative.

In debugging I see the condition is working fine, but when it comes to `SUM`, it just does that without sign, which means that instead of sum `(-A + -B)`, it does `( A + B )`

Can somebody help me please? Thanks.

Comment: One issue could be, you change the value in the structure, but it is not written back to the internal table. Other problem is that AT END OF ... ( +SUM) does not take into account the WHERE condition of the LOOP, which means the value will be calculated for all lines of the internal table. Seeing what lines are in the internal table would help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you multiply with -1, you only update the local variable `wa_prcd`, but not the original table `t_prcd`. `SUM` however only takes into account what's in `t_prcd`.

The fix thus is simply to separate the update from the sum step:

```
SORT t_prcd BY knumh kschl.

" use a reference or field-symbol to update the table in-place
LOOP AT t_prcd REFERENCE INTO DATA(ref_prcd)
    WHERE knumh = wa_wcocoh-knumh AND kschl = wa_wcocoh-kschl
      AND vbtyp = 'C'.
  ref_prcd->netwr = ref_prcd->netwr * ( -1 ).
  ref_prcd->kwmeng = ref_prcd->kwmeng * ( -1 ).
ENDLOOP.

LOOP AT t_prcd INTO DATA(wa_prcd)
    WHERE knumh = wa_wcocoh-knumh AND kschl = wa_wcocoh-kschl.
  AT END OF knumh.
    SUM.
    MOVE EXACT wa_prcd-netwr TO wa_talv-val_vendido.
    MOVE wa_prcd-kwmeng TO wa_talv-quant_vendido.
  ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thank you Florian,It makes total sense now, because when I was debugging, I saw that the minus sign became "lost" on the move step..

There is one more thing, in the way that you told me I can display negative numbers by multiply for (-1), but what I need is sum those negative numbers, that´s why I made the sum **at the end of** . Can I make something like Subtract there or Sum those negative numbers?

Comment: I don’t completely understand what you want to calculate and thus cannot advice yet. Imagine t_prcd contained two rows with the values 42 and 5 in netwr. What should be the result? -42 - 5 = -47? In case it’s this then this is exactly what my sample code will calculate. Or do you aim at a subtraction of the form 42 - 5 = 37?

Comment: Sorry Florian, it was the first option you said... I was thinking and looking at the code  in the wrong way, plus, in the rest of my program I had one more error which was making the final result wrong as well.. 
One more time, thank you, you really helped me! :)

Comment: @DavidTeixeira, if he really helped you then mark answer as solution, reward the answerer